# Ajax request: undefined

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, request

Hello there i wanted to request an api with ajax.
The api has plain json (what i thought)
now i set up an ajax request in javascript but i get an undefined error for the variables.I think i know the problem but I dont know an answer yet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', loadUsers);


// Load Github USers

function loadUsers(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xhr.open("GET", "dontKnowtheUrl", true);


    xhr.onload = function()
                {

                        if(this.status == 200){

                            var stats = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
                            var output = "";
                            for(var i in stats){
                                output += 
                                '<div class="user">' +
                                '<ul>' +
                                '<li>p_level: '+stats[i].p_level+'</li>'+
                                '<li>p_currentmmr: '+stats[i].p_currentmmr+'</li>' +
                                '</ul>' +
                                '</div>';
                            }
                            document.getElementById("users").innerHTML = output;
                        }

                }


                xhr.send();
}
```

This was the javascript part 
the json file from the api looks like this

```
     {"results":
    [{"p_id":"test",
    "p_name":"test",
    "p_level":"test",
    "p_platform":"test",
    "p_user":"test",
    "p_currentmmr":"test",
    "p_currentrank":"test",
    "kd":"test"},
    {"p_id":"test",
    "p_name":"test",
    "p_level":"test",
    "p_platform":"test",
    "p_user":"test",
    "p_currentmmr":"test",
    "p_currentrank":"test",
    "kd":"test"}],
    "totalresults":2}
```

My Guess is that the json file isnt a normal array because it contains the "results": and "totalresults" property.
Does Anyone know how to fix it without getting into the json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to loop through stats.results instead of just stats, see the following example:

```
function loadUsers(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xhr.open("GET", "dontKnowtheUrl", true);


    xhr.onload = function()
                {

                        if(this.status == 200){

                            var stats = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
                            var output = "";
                            for(var i in stats.results){
                                var row = stats.results[i];
                                output += 
                                '<div class="user">' +
                                '<ul>' +
                                '<li>p_level: '+row.p_level+'</li>'+
                                '<li>p_currentmmr: '+row.p_currentmmr+'</li>' +
                                '</ul>' +
                                '</div>';
                            }
                            document.getElementById("users").innerHTML = output;
                        }

                }


                xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: Yup, you also have to change the output like "stats.results[i].p_level" and dont let stay like "stats[i].p_level" same goes for the other variable thank you

Comment: You'll need to update `stats.results[i].p_level` & `stats.results[i].p_currentmmr` see [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lawlesss/3qvr0es6/14/)

Comment: Updated my answer to fix it, thanks for catching that!